# Copy on-prem data to S3 using AWS Data Pipeline

Tags: amazon-data-pipeline

How do I import data from an on-prem SQL database to an Amazon S3 using the AWS Data Pipeline? 
Links to any tutorials will greatly help me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run a Task Runner on-prem.  That task runner can execute a pipeline that can export data from SQL data base to S3.

If your database is MySQL, it can directly export the data out.  As shown in the below tutorial.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-copydata-mysql.html

If it is not MySQL, then you need to write an export job yourself.  For eg. use Talend DI to create an ETL script and wrap the Talend Job in a Shell Activity.

There is also an on-prem Task Runner template.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-localmysqltords.html

Comment: I installed the TaskRunner on my system. Followed all the instructions for SQL database to S3. But the Pipeline gets stuck at "WAITING_FOR_RUNNER". I have the right IAM creds and same workgroup. MySQL access is fine too. Any ideas?

Comment: If your credentials and data pipeline endpoint are already correct when you are launching Task Runner, then may be there is a proxy issue?  Is port 443 open?  Also, do you need to specify a HTTP proxy host and port?

Comment: Could it be because I'm using a virtual Linux machine?

Comment: It may be because of network settings.  You could test connectivity to various AWS hosted services using curl/wget.  It is not just because it is a virtual machine.